# Wrapping of comma separated data in bash to a fixed line length

Tags: bash, word-wrap

Hi I would like to wrap the following comma separated data:

```
-X, run, abs, absolute, accept, accept, alarm, schedule, atan2, arctangent, bind, binds, binmode, prepare, bless, create, caller, get, chdir, change, chmod, changes, chomp, remove, chop, remove, chown, change, chr, get, chroot, make, close, close, closedir, close, connect, connect, continue, optional, cos, cosine, crypt, one-way, dbmclose, breaks, dbmopen, create, defined, test, delete, deletes, die, raise, do, turn, dump, create, each, retrieve, endgrent, be, endhostent, be, endnetent, be, endprotoent, be, endpwent, be, endservent, be, eof, test, eval, catch, exec, abandon, exists, test, exit, terminate, exp, raise, fcntl, file, fileno, return, flock, lock, fork, create, format, declare, formline, internal, getc, get, getgrent, get, getgrgid, get, getgrnam, get, gethostbyaddr, get, gethostbyname, get, gethostent, get, getlogin, return, getnetbyaddr, get, getnetbyname, get, getnetent, get, getpeername, find, getpgrp, get, getppid, get, getpriority, get, getprotobyname, get, getprotobynumber, get, getprotoent, get, getpwent, get, getpwnam, get, getpwuid, get, getservbyname, get, getservbyport, get, getservent, get, getsockname, retrieve, getsockopt, get, glob, expand, gmtime, convert, goto, create, grep, locate, hex, convert, import, patch, int, get, ioctl, system-dependent, join, join, keys, retrieve, kill, send, last, exit, lc, return, lcfirst, return, length, return, link, create, listen, register, local, create, localtime, convert, log, retrieve, lstat, stat, m//, match, map, apply, mkdir, create, msgctl, SysV, msgget, get, msgrcv, receive, msgsnd, send, my, declare, next, iterate, no, unimport, oct, convert, open, open, opendir, open, ord, find, pack, convert, package, declare, pipe, open, pop, remove, pos, find, print, output, printf, output, prototype, get, push, append, q/STRING/, singly, qq/STRING/, doubly, quotemeta, quote, qw/STRING/, quote, qx/STRING/, backquote, rand, retrieve, read, fixed-length, readdir, get, readlink, determine, recv, receive, redo, start, ref, find, rename, change, require, load, reset, clear, return, get, reverse, flip, rewinddir, reset, rindex, right-to-left, rmdir, remove, s///, replace, scalar, force, seek, reposition, seekdir, reposition, select, reset, semctl, SysV, semget, get, semop, SysV, send, send, setgrent, prepare, sethostent, prepare, setnetent, prepare, setpgrp, set, setpriority, set, setprotoent, prepare, setpwent, prepare, setservent, prepare, setsockopt, set, shift, remove, shmctl, SysV, shmget, get, shmread, read, shmwrite, write, shutdown, close, sin, return, sleep, block, socket, create, socketpair, create, sort, sort, splice, add, split, split, sprintf, formatted, sqrt, square, srand, seed, stat, get, study, optimize, sub, declare, substr, get, symlink, create, syscall, execute, sysread, fixed-length, system, run, syswrite, fixed-length, tell, get, telldir, get, tie, bind, time, return, times, return, tr///, transliterate, truncate, shorten, uc, return, ucfirst, return, umask, set, undef, remove, unlink, remove, unpack, convert, unshift, prepend, untie, break, use, load, utime, set, values, return, vec, test, wait, wait, waitpid, wait, wantarray, get, warn, print, write, print, y///, transliterate,
```

such that a line break is added at the last comma before a 70 character line length.  Preferable this could be done in some kind of bash one liner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo 'your, text, here' | fold -sw 70
```

That should give you the output you want. Instead of using echo you can pipe it from a file or wherever else you're getting it from, or you can just use the fold command directly and paste it in on stdin.

The "-w 70" in fold tells it to wrap after 70 characters per line, and the -s tells it to wrap on the spaces after each comma.

Comment: +1 Perfect, thanks.  SO should allow immediate accepted answers, but there is a two minute delay I guess.

Comment: Thanks much, you finally bumped my reputation high enough to post comments! :) And glad I could help!

Comment: Note that that assumes that there are no spaces within elements of the comma-separated list; it's not actually looking for the commas, just looking for spaces.

Comment: This is a good point. fold is (surprisingly) not nearly flexible enough to handle anything other than spaces or hard-wrapping. It's actually a pretty poor tool, it just happens to work adequately in this case. I don't know if there's anything better out there.

Comment: Fortunately my data had commas and spaces.  I suppose you could do a sed command first to make sure all commas are preceded by a space.  I would be interested in alternatives that would work for just commas, if you are aware of some @intuited and @cecilkorik.

Answer (score 5):

In response to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993341/wrapping-of-comma-separated-data-in-bash-to-a-fixed-line-length/2993392#comment-4047841) about cases where spaces might be embedded between commas:

I think you're on the right track with using `sed`.  One option that you would have is to map all spaces to some unused character, then map commas to spaces, `fold`, then revert the original mappings.  But I think this will leave you with weird things like lines that begin with spaces.

So it seems like you would want to just remap any spaces not preceded by a comma to some character or sequence that you know isn't present in the text, and then invert to switch them back.

For example,

```
echo "$blahblah" | sed 's/\([^,]\) /\1\t/g' | fold -s | sed 's/\t/ /g
```

would work if there are no tab characters in the text, and if there are not going to be consecutive embedded spaces.

If there are, I think you'll need to use something a bit more complex like

```
echo "$blahblah" | \
    perl -pe 's/([^, ])( +)/$1 . "_" x length($2)/ge' | \
    fold -s | \
    tr _ ' '
```

The `/ge` makes each substitution value be evaluated as a perl expression.

The `tr` at the end is basically equivalent to the closing `sed` in the last command.

This assumes that the character "_" is not guaranteed to not occur in your source text.  There are certainly better characters to be chosen, e.g. an unused control character like, say, ^V.  If you use a modern `perl` to do the translation at the end you can, I think, use some obscure, multibyte unicode character.

This suggestion is pretty off-the-cuff, and has some obvious problems.  For example, it won't break after a comma unless there's a space there.  This might not really be what you want.  It may well be worth it to do some digging around on CPAN/PyPI/etc. for something more robust.  Or you could write your own folding utility...